# PL/SQL perform multiple selects looping over array of values, aggregating result

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I need to produce a set of rows wherein each one is the result of a complex select, and each select is based on a value from another list.

In other words, I need to perform a task like:

```
select * from ( 
    select col1, col2, col3 from data_table where guid=my_guid 
    order by col1)
    where rownum<=1
```

except that I need to perform this for a sequence of values of `my_guid` taken from another table, and get a union of the results suitable for selecting from.

Simply saying `where guid in (select * from guid_list)` will produce only one result because of rownum, but I want the top-ranked row associated with each guid instead.

I'm having some trouble figuring out what the correct way to do this is.

In an SQL variant with an aggregator that returns the first result, I could just do:

```
select col1, first(col2), first(col3) from data_table
    order by col1 group by guid
```

While debugging, I don't have write access to the database, so I'd like to avoid solutions involving creating temporary tables, procedures, or functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join your tables together (rather than using a second subquery, though that would also work), and use an analytic function to assign a ranking to the results based on each guid. Something like:

```
select col1, col2, col3 from ( 
  select dt.col1, dt.col2, dt.col3,
    row_number() over (partition by dt.guid order by col1) as rn
  from guid_list gl
  join data_table dt on dt.guid=gl.guid 
)
where rn = 1;
```

You can include the guid itself in the subquery if you need that in the result set.

If you want to do it just with aggregate functions and without the subquery you could also do something like:

```
select min(dt.col1) as col1,
  min(col2) keep (dense_rank first order by dt.col1) as col2,
  min(col3) keep (dense_rank first order by dt.col1) as col3
from guid_list gl
join data_table dt on dt.guid=gl.guid 
group by dt.guid;
```

[Read more about `keep dense_rank first`.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions056.htm).